# Warum sitzt der Schalk im Nacken?

Tags: etymology, phrase

Bei Leuten, die zu Späßen aufgelegt sind, kann man sagen:

> Dem Hans springt der Schalk aus dem Gesicht.
>
> Der Lieselotte springt der Schalk aus den Augen.

Das kann ich mir noch gut bildlich vorstellen, denn man sieht den Spaß gleich am Lachen und am Augenzwinkern.

Warum sagt man aber auch:

> Dem Hans sitzt der Schalk im Nacken.

Woher kommt diese Redewendung?

Comment: Na sowas, "spring der Schalk" hab ich noch nie gehört oder gelesen.  Öfter mal was Neues... ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ich habe auf dieser [Seite der Deutschen Welle über Wortspiele](http://www.podcast.de/episode/404480/Wortspiele) Folgendes gefunden:

> Die Wendung den *Schalk im Nacken haben* bezieht sich auf einen Menschen, der gleichsam von einem schalkhaften Dämon besessen ist, doch so, dass ihm der Wicht hinten im Nacken oder hinter den Ohren sitzt, so dass ihn der Genarrte nicht sehen kann. Die Redensart ist seit dem 16. Jahrhundert belegt.

Ursprünglich verstand man unter einem Schalk einen Knecht oder Diener. Gewisse Wörter, die heute noch verwendet werden, deuten darauf hin, z. B. "Marschall", der früher Aufseher über die Pferde war.

Später wurde der Begriff "Schalk" in Zusammenhang mit Menschen von knechtischer und boshafter Gesinnung verwendet und schließlich erhielt er die heutige Bedeutung einer Person, die ohne böse Absicht in launiger Verstellung einen listigen Scherz macht.

In einen [weiteren Artikel, der übrigens ebenfalls von der Deutschen Welle](http://www.dw-world.de/dw/article/0,1564,1708673,00.html) stammt, wird behauptet, die Redewendung sei mehrfach belegt:

> [Die Redensart ist] alt und seit dem 16. Jahrhundert reichlich belegt. Der Bildhintergrund der versteckten Schelmerei ist allerdings im heutigen Sprachgebrauch fast ganz verloren gegangen, was die Redewendung der Schalk guckt ihm aus den Augen belegt. Deutlich geblieben ist die ursprüngliche Verstellung des Spaßmachers jedoch noch im folgenden Volkslied, wenn der Liebhaber nicht weiß, woran er ist, wenn er über seine Geliebte klagend sagt:
>
> *Ihr tragt ein Schalk im Nacken,
>
>   Man weiß nicht, treibt Ihr Ernst oder Scherz,
>
>   Thut Honigküchel backen,
>
>   Dazwischen Dörner hacken,
>
>   Verspott redlichs Herz.*

---

Auf dem Weblog von Lisa Neun gibt es eine [schöne Illustration](http://www.lisaneun.com/l9log/2006_09_18.html):

[image: Schalk im Nacken comic]

Comment: Ich stelle mir gerade den "Wicht" vor und dabei springt er mir aus den Augen :)

Answer (score 7):

[Hier](http://www.iablis.de/iab2/content/view/165/106/) wird behauptet, es sei ungeklärt.

> Was hat es aber andererseits mit der gängigen Redensart auf sich, jemandem sitze förmlich der Schalk im Nacken? Rührt sie vielleicht daher, dass Hofnarren anlässlich überbordender Heiterkeitsausbrüche gelegentlich die Narrenkappe ins Genick gerutscht sein könnte? Oder spielt der Schalk im Nacken auf das sich häufig sträubende Nackenhaar bei jenen an, die zu unfreiwilligen Opfern des spöttischen Schabernacks wurden, vor dem es galt, auf der Hut zu sein, um ungeschoren davonzukommen? Genaues weiss man nicht. Deshalb kratzen sich die Sprachgelehrten zu diesem Thema verlegen die Nackenhaare, was zumindest die Hirnströme im Hinterkopf anregen soll.

Die Vermutung, die splattne schon gefunden hat, wird dort auch erwähnt:

> Einer anderen Hypothese zufolge soll es sich bei der stehenden Wendung vom ›Schalk im Nacken‹ um einen listigen Kobold gehandelt haben, der manch einem bisweilen impertinente Frechheiten ins Ohr flüsterte und ihn dazu ermunterte, ein loses Mundwerk zu führen.

Comment: +1 Interessante Glosse und hübsche Alliteration: *Schelme, Schalk und Schabernack*

Answer (score 1):

Many of the attempts at explanation quoted here are more than a little contrived, aren't they?
"Der Schalk" lends itself quite readily to an anthropomorphic personification imo (English has something similar: imp -> impish).
Also, the image of someone sittig on one's shoulders is about as common as... something very common indeed - right? Probably because it is the most efficient way to carry someone.
So a little personification of "being a prankster" *riding* someone (i.e. controlling them) does make immediate sense imo - without the need for further elaboration (e.g. in the first quote of the first answer, the fact that the "Schalk" is out of the "carriers" sightline is massively overinterpreted - it makes about as much sense as saying "he's a prankster but he doesn't know it").

Comment: The idea is that somebody who has "Schalk im Nacken" cracks jokes without really intending to, i.e. not under control, like being driven.

Comment: Echt? Oh, so habe ich das bisher nie verstanden... für mich war das immer jemand, der einfach eine "schalkhafte Ader" hat (ohne implizierten Kontrollverlust). Bin ich da ganz auf dem Holzweg?

Comment: Für mein Gefühl ist jemand mit "Schalk im Nacken" quasi das kleine bißchen witziger, als lustig ist, wenn Du verstehst was ich meine. Aber wie das bei solchen Redewendungen ist, definiert sie sich jeder ein bißchen wie er mag, und mit der Zeit gibt es keine "wirkliche" Bedeutung mehr.